# Invoke a Google sheet macro in Dialog flow fullfillment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have created an agent in Dialog flow. I have added a macro on Google sheet to add a new row. The same has been published as a web app. When I execute the web app from the browser, it works well and I see a new row added to the google sheet as desired. I want to use the macro in Dialog flow for fulfillment.

However, the action is not resulting in desired using webhooks. The link to a web app is here: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyJHW0HlopUtfCB6naxgxJ2mooR5g980jJlhR-sGgMe0Uqyww/exec

I have not generated any API-Keys. Does it require having an API-Key to invoke the macro from Dialog flow?

Answer (score 0):

Your webapp requires user authentication (and, probably, authorization). Dialogflow is not able to "log in" to your webapp, so the webhook fulfillment fails.